# Не совсем понятно почему значений больше

Tags: java

Читаю книгу Head First Java и при решении задачи возник вопрос - "Почему значений больше чем я думал?"
Вот следующий код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;

        while(x>1) {
            x--;
            if(x<3) {
                System.out.println("small x");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне кажется в командной строке должна быть одна фраза:

> small x

Т.к. "1" в цикле и "2" в условном операторе не включительны. А в результате появляется две фразы. Прошу объяснить в чем я ошибаюсь?!

Comment: так `x<2` или `x<3` ? %)  Если 3, то поясните, почему вы считаете, что фраза должна появиться только один раз?))

Comment: Извиняюсь за первоначальное заблуждение. На самом деле x<3, я допустил ошибку, когда записывал код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Декремент `x--;` находится между условием цикла и условием вывода сообщения, поэтому значение до цикла было 3, а в цикле после декремента уже 2, и потом до цикла 2, а в цикле уже 1, поэтому два раза и выводится.

Соответственно, чтобы получить вывод в консоль только один раз, нужно `x--;` поместить в конец цикла, а не в его начало.

Comment: Соответственно, что получить вывод в консоль только один раз, нужно `x--;` поместить в конец цикла, а не в его начало.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассмотрим цикл

```
while(x>1) {
    x--;
    if(x<2) {
    System.out.println("small x");
}
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет в одном случае: когда `x` меньше 2, то есть когда внутри тела цикла `x` равно 1. Это может произойти только в одном случае, когда в самом начале итерации цикла `x` равно 2.

После этого в предложении

```
    x--;
```

значение `x` будет уменьшено, и условие в предложении `if` будет истинным.

После выхода из данной итерации `x` будет равно 1, и в виду условия цикла

```
while(x>1) {
      ^^^^
```

цикл прекратит свою работу.

Следовательно только один раз на консоль будет выдано сообщение

```
small x
```

Вы не можете получить два таких сообщения.

EDIT: Если ж изменить условие цикла с

```
    if(x<2) {
```

на

```
    if(x<3) {
```

то на консоль будет выдано два сообщения. Первое сообщение будет выдано, когда при очередной итерации цикла `x` будет равно 3 (в этом случае после выполнения предложения `x--;` `x` станет равным 2 перед вычислением условия в `if` предложении). И второе сообщение будет выдано, когда в следующей итерации цикла, при которой начальное значение `x` будет равно 2.

Итого на консоль будет выдано два сообщения.